# Difference between the performance of to_date(:PARAMETER, 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('20/11/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I have a query like this:

```sql
select * from table where dat_reg between to_date('19/11/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('19/11/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1
```

On PL/SQL, the performance is perfect. But when I put this on report:

```sql
select * from table where dat_reg between to_date(:DAT_BEGIN, 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date(:DAT_END, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1
```

My performance drops a lot. Why?

The parameters are of type character

Comment: how are you passing the parameter to report ? do you have index on this field ?

Comment: @Andrew yes, it has. Im passing the parameter in c# calling the report server with URL Encoding Reference

Comment: try to use `dat_reg between :DAT_BEGIN and :DAT_END + 1` after defining those parameters as date instead of char within the Reports.

Comment: How many rows do you see when running the query in "PL/SQL" (what is it? PL/SQL Developer?), and how many rows does the report return? Does the report display "total number of pages" (e.g. Page 1/200)?

Comment: Which dates have you passed to the report the FIRST TIME you ran it?

Comment: @littlefoot just 1 page with 6 rows in average

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan I tried, continued the same thing

Comment: @Kirill Leontev I passed 16/11/2019 and 16/11/2019